# how to create a for loop that creates multiple arrays in Python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

A part of my code has:

```
pkG1 = kGlobalParts(dof1,k1)
pkG2 = kGlobalParts(dof2,k2)
pkG3 = kGlobalParts(dof3,k3)
pkG4 = kGlobalParts(dof4,k4)
pkG5 = kGlobalParts(dof5,k5)
pkG6 = kGlobalParts(dof6,k6)
pkG7 = kGlobalParts(dof7,k7)
pkG8 = kGlobalParts(dof8,k8)
pkG9 = kGlobalParts(dof9,k9)
pkG10 = kGlobalParts(dof10,k10)
pkG11 = kGlobalParts(dof11,k11)
```

where kGlobalParts is a function that returns an 11x11 array. Is there any way I can do this quicker? maybe using a for loop?

Comment: all `pkG`, `dof`, and `k` should've been lists in the first place, that way you could do it easily with a for loop, right?

Comment: If `kGlobalParts` returns an array, it probably allows using arrays for `pkG`, `dof` and `k` and using them as arguments, with something that would look like `pkG = kGlobalParts(dof, k, axis=?)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you make  array pkG = [pkG1,...,pkG11] etc, you can try:

```
pkG = []
for i in range(len(dof)):
    pkG.append(kGlobalParts(dof[i],k[i]))
```

where you define k1 to k11 in array k and also with dof.

Comment: It is best practice to use `for dd, kk in zip(dof, k):`